# How to select URL from Top X Google Search results with BeatifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have this code, that shows me the first result (URL) from google search ranking.

Can anyone show me how to expand this code that I see the first 10, 20 or X results form the search results.
But I need only the URL. :)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

search = 'find_this'
url = 'https://www.google.com/search'

headers = {
    'Accept' : '*/*',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.82',
}
parameters = {'q': search}

content = requests.get(url, headers = headers, params = parameters).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')


search = soup.find(id = 'search')
first_link = search.find('a')

print(first_link['href'])
```

I made my own loop but I was not able to find the right Variabl how includes the search results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select the url of the results use `find_all()` or `select()` over `find()`, because these methods provide a `ResultSet` of all and not only the first element.

Used a [`css selector`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) in this example to extract the first 10 results from your result page:

```
for e in soup.select('a:has(h3)'):
    print (e.get('href'))
```

---

To select and iterate the results from all available pages from your `soup` you could go with:

```
for p in soup.select('[role="navigation"] a[aria-label]'):
    print ('https://www.google.com'+p.get('href'))
```

Output:

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=find+this&ei=ngTKZP_uPOqqxc8PgPSdwAE&start=10&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwj_tYzouL2AAxVqVfEDHQB6BxgQ8tMDegQIAhAE
https://www.google.com/search?q=find+this&ei=ngTKZP_uPOqqxc8PgPSdwAE&start=20&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwj_tYzouL2AAxVqVfEDHQB6BxgQ8tMDegQIAhAG
https://www.google.com/search?q=find+this&ei=ngTKZP_uPOqqxc8PgPSdwAE&start=30&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwj_tYzouL2AAxVqVfEDHQB6BxgQ8tMDegQIAhAI
https://www.google.com/search?q=find+this&ei=ngTKZP_uPOqqxc8PgPSdwAE&start=40&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwj_tYzouL2AAxVqVfEDHQB6BxgQ8tMDegQIAhAK
https://www.google.com/search?q=find+this&ei=ngTKZP_uPOqqxc8PgPSdwAE&start=50&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwj_tYzouL2AAxVqVfEDHQB6BxgQ8tMDegQIAhAM
...
```